# why is wcf duplex required?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

WCF duplex performs a callback after a method has run on the server that then runs code on the client.

If i want to execute a method on the client from the server at the push of a button on the server then i don't think WCF duplex is appropriate.

Why would i not just create a client and a server at each end of my 2 applications?

Comment: Is all the code necessary to understand this? Or could you summarize better? This seems like a lot of code for what might be a simple question...

Comment: thanks justin - i agree but i did want to explain everything in one go - people keep asking me for app.config , server code and client code , contracts etc so its all there

Comment: in a line is duplex only for callbacks - i want to run a client side function from the server. NOT a callback though.

Comment: For future reference, I would suggest going with what you feel is pertinent and adding it if asked. You probably will get better responses, and it will help you learn what is and is not pertinent. Just throwing everything at us because you are not sure is a bit of a copout IMO

Comment: ok - let me update the question

Comment: If the server needs to tell clients of something new, a more traditional approach is [Polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)).  [Pushing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) the data to clients is a much better user experience and can be a better technical choice.  WCF Duplex enables you to do Push from a server.

Comment: "WCF Duplex enables you to do Push from a server" how ? - callbacks are of no use to me

Comment: @ TylerOhlsen - the only way i could get your suggestion going was to create a server on the client aswell

Comment: This is a very old question so hopefully it is still being monitored. @user1438082 asked **Why would i not just create a client and a server at each end of my 2 applications?**. To my understanding, duplex does not require SSL certificates on both Server and Clients (assuming you want HTTPS), while having a server at both ends requires that Server and Clients have their own SSL certificates. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was one of the people that commented on your previous question so I probably owe you an answer here :o)

You have posted rather a lot of code and I have not looked at it in detail. However, in general terms, there *is* a reason for using wsDualHttpBinding and duplex contracts in general instead of more of a peer-to-peer approach where you have services on both sides, as follows:

The duplex approach is appropriate where you have a clearly defined server that is running permanently. This provides the *hub* of the interaction. The idea is that clients are in some way more transient than the server. The clients can start up and shut down or move location and the server does not need to be aware of them in advance. When the client starts up, it is pre-configured to know where the server is, so it can "register" itself with the server.

In contrast, the server does not need to be preconfigured to know where the clients are. It starts up and can run independently of any clients. It just accepts "registrations" from all clients that have valid credentials whenever they come online, and can continue to run after the client goes offline. Also, if the client moves, it just re-registers itself with the server at its new location.

So the server is in some sense a more "important" part of the system. No client can participate in the communication without the server, but the server can operate independently of any client.

To do this with WCF duplex service, you have to do some extra work yourself to implement the publish/subscribe behaviour. Fortunately, the MSFT Patterns and Practises team have provided some guidance on how to do it

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752254.aspx

This is fundamentally different from a genuine peer-to-peer approach where there is no well-defined hub (i.e. server) for the network and each node can come and go without affecting the overall functioning of the network.

Comment: ok - here is the problem though above i state "If i want to execute a method on the client from the server at the push of a button on the server then i don't think WCF duplex is appropriate." - This is not duplex at all - i need a server on the client i believe

Comment: please tell me i am completely wrong here but noone has yet to convince me otherwise

Comment: You may not be able to put a server on the client if you do not control the client.  You would have to punch a hole in their firewall to get the server hosted in their environment.

Comment: And no, you do need to put a server on the client.  WCF Duplex is what allows you to not have to put a server on the client.

Comment: TylerOhlsen i followed this but i dont see how i can add a simple button the server interface to initiate a method on the client.  - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/a-simple-duplex-service-in-wcf/

Comment: If you do not control your client's environment (to punch a hole in the client's firewall in order to host a wcf server), your only option is for the client to initiate the first call.  Your server will not be able to communicate with the client first.

Comment: So, on app startup, your client can check in with the server and subscribe to some event (which tells the server to hold onto a reference to the client's callback).

Comment: If you want the communication to be specific to one client, you might want to add a key of some sort that is unique per client at the time of the client subscription so that the server can have a list of connected clients by key.

Comment: See also [Design Patterns: List-Based Publish-Subscribe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752254.aspx)

Comment: No. with duplex service, you can have the service call the client by pushing a button on the server. You have to implement a publish/subscribe pattern. I've updated my answer with some more info.

Comment: i think that's the answer i was looking for the past 4 days publish/subscribe pattern. i will give that a go.

Comment: Also FYI, you wouldn't necessarily need to expose a publish method.  That could be done internal to the server application or in another (more secure) endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

WCF Duplex is used when you have a Publish/Subscribe setting (also known as the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)). Let's say you have a service that subscribes for notifications of some sort (e.g. new email). Normally, you would need to check periodically for updates. Using WCF Duplex, the subscriber can be notified automatically by the publisher when there are updates.

Comment: yes - i understand but i dont think this is for me - here i was told it was but now that i have spent a day coding it all up i disagree http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178434/wcf-client-and-server thoughts welcome

Comment: It is difficult to say from a superficial description, but from the little I could understand, it probably isn't what you need. Keep in mind that this is about the manner of processing and communication that should take place between endpoints, not necessarily about whether they are P2P or not.