# Access IIS IP Blocked List using impersonation account

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, ip-address

In my ASp Net web forms application, impersonation is tunred on and a username and password is set. `<identity impersonate="true" userName="impersonationaccount" password="*************" />`

One of the security features of the website is that it will check the IIS list of blocked IP addresses. The problem is that this impersonation account needs admin privileges (windows account access) on the production server and this is not desired.

The error that occurs is this:

```
Filename: redirection.config
Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
```

Here is the code that accesses the IP black list from IIS.

```
/// <summary>
/// Constructor
/// </summary>
public IPBlocker(string siteName)
{
    this.serv = new ServerManager();
    this.config = this.serv.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
    this.ipSecuritySection = this.config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/ipSecurity", siteName);
    this.ipSecurityColl = this.ipSecuritySection.GetCollection();
}
```

At the line where it tries to get the `ipSecurity` section it throws the error.

Is there a way to programatically access this file with elevated permissions just to be able to read this file?

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: You may be better off creating a remote service application, that will be running with proper permissions.  Then you simply call the service to gather the data you need.

Comment: @Greg - It would be great if all of the functionality was in this application but this solution may be best due to security concerns.

Comment: Well, my thought was separation would allow the service to have the *full* permission it requires to interact with *IIS* in the manner your seeking.  Since it is a separated application, your original web application would interact with the service.  Alleviating the excessive permission you would provide to it.

Comment: @Greg - Sorry I wasn't clear. The security concerns I mentioned were about granting elevated access to the web application, because many of the solutions I searched online stated a higher risk from doing this. But like you said, the service would have the permissions required and the web app would just call it when needed.

Comment: That is what I assumed, that is why I recommended separation.  It will minimize the permission levels of your web-application, while exposing what you need.  Anything with IIS will require full permission.

Comment: @Greg - If you would like to create an answer with your comments above I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper approach would be to create a remote service application.  This will do the following:

- Configured with proper security permissions.
- Will ensure you don't give your web application too much control.

Security is one those areas that are quite tricky, but one detail you should attempt to adhere to:

> You shouldn't provide too much control to an application, it is better
>   to abstract or ask for the control that you need, when you need it. 
>   Otherwise you risk your application exposing other areas within the
>   system.

Since your attempting to interact directly with Internet Information System (IIS) through the `ServerManager.dll` you'll need **full permission**.  This is something your web application shouldn't have.  You should separate them, that way your web-application can keep its current permissions, while the service will have full permissions to invoke.

You could do this with several approaches to implement your services.

One approach would be Windows Communication Foundation (WCF), which information and tutorial links can be found on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178434/wcf-client-and-server/15178690#15178690).